# Not getting the full output out of a list

Tags: python, exif, folium

## Objective

I'm trying to extract the GPS "Latitude" and "Longitude" data from a bunch of JPG's and I have been successful so far but my main problem is that when I try to write the coordinates to a text file for example I see that only 1 set of coordinates was written compared to my console output which shows that every image was extracted. Here is an example: [Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXl4Z.png) and here is my text file that is supposed be a mirror output along my console: [Text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8rBm.png)
I don't fully understand whats the problem and why it won't just write all of them instead of one. I believe it is being overwritten somehow or the 'GPSPhoto' module is causing some issues.

## Code

```
from glob import glob
from GPSPhoto import gpsphoto

# Scan jpg's that are located in the same directory.
data = glob("*.jpg")

# Scan contents of images and GPS values.
for x in data:
    data = gpsphoto.getGPSData(x)
    data = [data.get("Latitude"), data.get("Longitude")]
    print("\nsource: {}".format(x), "\n ↪ {}".format(data))

# Write coordinates to a text file.
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    print('Coordinates:', data, file=f)
```

I have tried pretty much everything that I can think of including: changing the write permissions, not using glob, no loops, loops, lists, no lists, different ways to write to the file, etc.
Any help is appreciated because I am completely lost at this point. Thank you.

Comment: Do you realize you've used "data" twice above?  You use data to get all the jpg files, but then you overwrite the original data with gpsphoto data.  So you threw your file list away on the first iteration through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the `data` variable each time through the loop, not appending to a list.

```
all_coords = []
for x in data:
    data = gpsphoto.getGPSData(x)
    all_coords.append([data.get("Latitude"), data.get("Longitude")])

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    print('Coordinates:', all_coords, file=f)
```